# Unexpected connection closed on GET request

Tags: node.js, http, heroku

I have a node js api hosted on heroku and two other vue-js apps linked to the API. The first vue js app works fine. The second one react strangely. The two first requests (Log-in and get a list of user) works fine but whatever i attempt to do then, even requesting the same list of user, the connection is lost and a CORS issue is logged.

The url of the two apps are in the `allowedOrigins` headers of the api and it works fine locally.

Here are the HTTP response when I attempt to get the user list for the second time or any other request :

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 18 Apr 2019 19:25:08 GMT
Server  Cowboy
```

and here are the logs of my server :

```
info heroku router req=0e6f8359… at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/v1/admin/get-all-users" host=domain.herokuapp.com request_id=0e6f8359-0f78-4b42-995d-fe34a6b6c658 fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=540 protocol=https
info heroku router req=8dd33943… at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/admin/get-all-users" host=domain.herokuapp.com request_id=8dd33943-4e34-4774-b0ec-0f2f893934cb fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=200 bytes=10915 protocol=https
info heroku router req=cc73307c… at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/v1/admin/get-all-users" host=domain.herokuapp.com request_id=cc73307c-18c5-45b9-844c-08e63d1f7ae6 fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=538 protocol=https
```

It doesn't seems to be an error of code. I do not have any idea of where it could come from, so i'm asking for help. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The third call is using `method=OPTIONS` instead of `method=GET`. You'll need to find a way to get your api to recognize the third request as a `GET` request.

Comment: `OPTIONS` are generated automatically and verify the request headers correspond to my sails api expectations (allowed origins, methods, header...) It works also this way with the first vue js app but the connection remains opened.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to fix this issue. I used a unical and global instance of axios imported in all my vuex store request.

```
const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': {
      toString () {
        return `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('admin-token')}`
      }
    },

    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

By creating a new instance of axios on each request,  my server doesn't send a 304  response.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

[...]

axios({
   baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
   url: '/api/v1/dr_claims/deliver-dr',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': {
          toString () {
             return `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('admin-token')}`
          }
      }
   }
})

[...]
```

I don't think this is the best way to handle this error but it seems ok.